# Laravel Undefined Request Variable

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a simple search/sort code snippet that I'm running on all of my models, and for some reason it is breaking on one of them. The model and controller file look pretty identical in what is brought in and such, so I'm not sure what the issue is. This code is designed to run off of URL tokens, such as: `/doctors?search=bob&sortBy=first_name&sort=asc`. Which works on all of my other models.

**Code Block**

```
// Searches, sorts, and filters
$search = $request->search;
$sort = ($request->sort == null ? 'asc' : $request->sort);
$sortBy = ($request->sortBy == null ? 'prescribe_date' : $request->sortBy);
```

This returns the following error: `Undefined variable: request`

And points to the lines in the code block above. I thought it might be because there was no ternary for a null search, but even fixing that points to the next $sort line.

Comment: can you show all function, I think you don't declare request on function?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set

> Request $request

as a parameter when you define your function? Like in [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#accessing-the-request) snippet.

Otherwise $request would be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain an instance of the current HTTP request via dependency injection, you should type-hint the Illuminate\Http\Request class on your controller method. The incoming request instance will automatically be injected by the service container:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->search;
    }
```